# Can I copy a table in one databsae from another database?

Tags: java, database

I need to copy one table from database A to database B. The challenge is I am using struts and have to write this code in Java. I tried to use copy command creating runtime process. But I get an exception. I used the command below:

```
Runtime Rt;
            Process Prc = null;
            String cmd = "";
            cmd="COPY FROM  id/pass@servicename1 to id/pass@servicename2 CREATE TABLE_C (*) USING (SELECT * FROM PROCESS_LOG )";

            Rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Prc = Rt.exec(cmd);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exception do you have? What database do you use?

Comment: I'm not sure how you expected the Java Runtime to understand that String. Where did you get it from? What database do you use? Are the two databases running on the same RDBMS?

Comment: @dbf I use oracle. error coming java.io.IOException: CreateProcess: COPY FROM id/pass@servicename1 to id/pass@servicename2 CREATE TABLE_C (*) USING (SELECT * FROM PROCESS_LOG )"; error=2

Comment: @David O'Meara well I am exporting from database by exp commnad by the same way. working fine. Why its failing for copy command?

Comment: What happens when you execute the copy command directly from the command line?

Comment: I figured it out. I used this commnad. Working fine

    cmd= "sqlplus id/pass@servicename @d:/TEST.SQL";

In the TEST.SQL I have written the copy command.

Comment: please submit this as an answer and then accept it (to assist future readers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I used this command and it is working fine.

```
cmd= "sqlplus id/pass@servicename @d:/TEST.SQL";
```

In the TEST.SQL I have written the copy command.